# Simplest way to create Renviron.site file

Tags: r, rstudio

In my opinion the simplest way to create .Renviron file is to use `usethis::edit_r_environ()`.
Is there any analogous command which can create .Renviron.site file ? I couldn't find that command. Or maybe you can figure out some other simply way to create .Renviron.site file ? Only ones I found were very involved and unclear.

Thanks guys

Comment: In my opinion, the simplest way is use of a text editor (could even be RStudio, which at its heart is a text editor). `help("Startup")` tells you where R is looking for these files (which are simple text files).

Comment: Okey, but for example Sys.getenv("R_ENVIRON") returns no path. Renviron.site file is not existing so that I can't edit them.

Comment: That's what the documentation says. Just create the file: Open a plain text editor (such as RStudio or Notepad), create a new file, save it as `<R_HOME>/etc/Renviron.site`.

Comment: Yea, you're right it's working. Could you add this as an answer so that I can accept it? ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These files are plain text files. You can create them with any text editor that can create `.txt` files.

So, if the file doesn't already exist:

- Open a plain text editor (such as RStudio or Notepad),
- create a new
  file (and add the desired content),
- save it, e.g., as
  `<R_HOME>/etc/Renviron.site`.

The locations where R is searching for these files are described in `help("Startup")`.